# Can 秘める mean to have?

Tags: translation, nuances

The sentence in question is

> 「いずれにしても、強大な力を秘めていたことは間違いない」

For me, this would mean something like

> "In any case, there is no doubt it was hiding its mighty power." (a)

However, Google translate gives the following sentence:

> "In any case, there is no doubt that he had a great power." (b)

Now, normally, I don't take stuff from Google translate at face value but in this case, I've seen other people translating this sentence both ways (both (a) and (b)).

Context-wise, the sentence appears as part of the following dialogue,

> 「ミュウです」
> 発掘隊員が石版を指すと、博士は感嘆の表情を浮かべた。
> 「神秘の力を持ち、大洪水を引き起こしたとか••••••荒地に作物を実らせ、人々に分け与えたとか••••••」
> 「天使か悪魔か」
> 「気まぐれなだけか」
> 研究員たちが後に続くと、博士は笑みを浮かべた。
> 「いずれにしても、強大な力を秘めていたことは間違いない」

and it translation (b) can fit too. According to [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%A7%98%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B) though, 秘める only has the meaning "to hide".

That being said, is (a) the correct translation? Is (b) possible as well?

Comment: Related: [Difference between 隠す and 秘める (to hide)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19540/difference-between-%e9%9a%a0-%e3%81%8b%e3%81%8f-%e3%81%99-and-%e7%a7%98-%e3%81%b2-%e3%82%81%e3%82%8b-to-hide/19543#19543) I think "have" is used "secretly hold" or something in the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three monolingual dictionaries I checked have both of the following definitions:

1. to conceal, to  hide
2. to have within itself, to possess (if not showily)

So how secretive it is depends on the context, but it's somewhere between 強大な力を宿している and 強大な力を隠している. I think "had a great power" is a reasonable translation in many cases.

Reference: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%A7%98%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B-612565

Answer (score 1):

To me, both (a) and (b) are correct though I feel (a) sounds more accurate as the letter 秘 itself means a secret so with める it sort of becomes a verb meaning "to secretly possess" or "to have something (that usually refers to something spiritual or a special power) without anyone's knowledge" so "to hide" in this instance and in my opinion is more accurate.